# Hiding content when deadline date is less than today’s date – rails 4

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails, so any help and advise would be much appreciated.

- i am trying to hide a job advert (with css) if it's `deadline` date is less than today's date.
- my code is not working as the advert is not being hidden
- would much appreciate it if one could advise me, or if there is a better efficient way of coding this

thank you

> views / adverts / index.html.erb

```
<table>   
 <thead>     
  <tr>   
   <th>Title</th>
   <th>Status</th>              
   <th>Content</th>       
   <th>Deadline</th>       
  </tr>   
 </thead>    
 <tbody>     
  <% @adverts.each do |advert| %>   
   <% if advert.deadline < Date.today %>   
   <div class="hide">    
    <tr>         
     <td><%= advert.title %></td>
     <td><%= “expired” %></td>        
     <td><%= advert.content %></td>      
     <td><%= advert.deadline %></td>        
    </tr> 
   </div >
   <% else %>   
    <div >    
     <tr>         
      <td><%= advert.title %></td>
      <td><%= “active” %></td> 
      <td><%= advert.content %></td>      
      <td><%= advert.deadline %></td>        
     </tr> 
    </div >
   <% end %>   
  <% end %>   
 </tbody> 
</table>
```

> application.css

```
.hide {
 display:none
}
```

Comment: Are the lack of speech quotes `"` around hide a typo?

Comment: just corrected that - but still does not work @japed

Comment: if you are going to hide those adverts, why do you need them in your collection ?, are you showing them somewhere else in the page ?, if not, why don't you just change your query to exclude those ?. In case you want to still use your 'if' statement, isn't your "expired" advert's deadline today ?, if so, that's the error, you are hiding adverts which expired date is yesterday or older.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of wrapping the **tr** with a **div**, just apply the ".hide" class to the **tr** in question. Divs shouldn't be used as a direct child in a table!

```
<% @adverts.each do |advert| %>   
   <% if advert.deadline < Date.today %>    
    <tr class="hide">         
     <td><%= advert.title %></td>
     <td><%= “expired” %></td>        
     <td><%= advert.content %></td>      
     <td><%= advert.deadline %></td>        
    </tr> 
<% else %>
```

Answer (score 1):

> FYI:
>
> Date.today differs from Date.current

--> `Date.current` also returns `Date.today` if timeZone is not set other wise 
      returns `Today's Date` of current time zone. We can verify this by changing the timezone.

If your doing comparisons you should always use `Date.current`

This is because if you're in a timezone that could be in a different day than UTC, and your timezone isn't set then you can have the situation where `Date.today == Date.tomorrow`

So it would be more preferable

```
<% if advert.deadline < Date.current %>
```